# Inverse Fourier Transform in Android

Tags: java, android, algorithm, fft

Are there any Java/Android libraries that have implemented the inverse fourier transform?  I've found a few that implement the fourier transform but none that implement its inverse.

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to apply this to?  Is it an array of sampled audio data?  A reverse Fourier transform is [fairly easy to implement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) in most cases.  You might try specifically looking into the [discrete Fourier Transform methods available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition)

Comment: The goal is take take in a spectrogram, or a series of spectra and then compute a audio buffer for each specta

Comment: okay, but what are the actual data values, and what is the data type?  You would likely have to buffer the data somehow and compute the DIFT (discrete inverse fourier transform) using that data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Fourier transform is *almost* its own inverse.

Specifically, if `F[]` is your Fourier transform,

```
F[ F[g(x)] ] = K g(-x)
```

(where `K` depends on the exact definition of your transform; see the relevant section [of the wikipedia article on DFT's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Expressing_the_inverse_DFT_in_terms_of_the_DFT))

The wikipedia article suggests a number of ways to get an inverse transform.  One way is to reverse the order of the input (specifically, swap x[n] with x[N-n]) before performing the transform.  Another is to conjugate your data before and after you perform the transform.  In any case, you will generally need to multiply by a constant factor, to recover your signal at its original amplitude.

In summary: it is quick and easy to use the regular transform to get the inverse, which is probably why they don't specifically provide one.

Comment: I would add that if you don't already *know* this property of the FFT but you want an inverse FFT for some purpose, you should get an introductory DSP book because there are other things you don't yet realize you don't know.